# Terminate a loop from a different thread with Rust

Tags: multithreading, loops, rust

I have a simple loop in a thread, and I'd like to stop the loop. Normally with Python, I would use a global variable to stop the loop, but I don't know for Rust.

I heard about channels, but I don't know how to pass a channel `Receiver` into my function which starts a new thread.

Comment: This question doesn't really show any effort. You say you "don't know how to pass a channel", but what have you tried? Passing an argument to a function is a very fundamental concept in most programming languages, and Rust is no different. If you don't know how to do that, you may want to hold off on multithreading as it's orders of magnitude more complicated.

Comment: And the docs for [std::sync::mpsc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html) give examples of moving a channel Sender into a new thread.

Comment: The doc say that only one thread can contain a specific receiver, and when i want to pass it in args, i can't because of <T>. I dont know wath to put there. The Receiver<T>. I want to pass a Receiver. Wath am i suposed to pass here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channels seem like overkill for a simple loop condition. You can use an [atomic variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html) instead which can be shared across threads.

Comment: Would you suggest passing the atomic variable to a function? OP might not know how to do that.

Comment: The problem with the mpsc asymmetry does not apply to atomics. they can be shared between any number of threads.